# put a default value to do a inner join instead of left or right join

Tags: sql

In relation between two table is it a good idea in term of performance to put a default value to do an inner join instead of left or right join?

Comment: I don't think such a performance implication would have much impact.  In any case, that isn't really a good reason to use a default value.